# Meta data not showing when I look up my website on google

Tags: typescript, next.js

Im using Nextjs 13.4.3 and I am getting an Untitled title and 'For full functionality of this site it is necessary to enable JavaScript. Here are the instructions how to enable JavaScript in your web browser.' as the description.

Here is how it looks when i look up my website: [google results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG9tk.png)

And here is my layout.tsx file:

```
import "../styles/globals.css";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

import { Inter } from "next/font/google";
import Head from "next/head";

import Footer from "@/components/footer";
import Navbar from "@/components/navbar";
const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] });

export const metadata = {
  title: "MHMA Web Design Company",
  description: "Transforming your digital presence with innovative web design solutions. We craft stunning and user-friendly websites that captivate your audience and drive results. Contact us to elevate your online brand today.",
};





export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
        <Navbar />
        {children}
        <Footer />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

I also tried to edit the page.tsx using the previous nextjs version's 'next/head' way but that didnt work as well

Comment: If you pushed the metadata lately, google needs some time to pick up the changes, I guess.

Comment: You should try using some browser extensions to check the meta data, if they're able to fetch that, then you will see that in Google as well (maybe after some time). Or just, open the website, view source and check if metadata is showing, if yes, then again, give some time

Comment: Check back in about a week and see if you get the same results.  Also check other search engines and compare